# Maximum 1-norm of matrix times unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

If $A$ is a $p \times p$ matrix, what is

$$\max_{||u||_2=1} ||Au||_1 ?$$

I am specifically interested in the case when $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: What are *your* thoughts on this?

Comment: It's easy when $A$ is identity, then the maximum is $\sqrt(p)$ since $u=(\sqrt(1/p),...)$.

Comment: Hint:  what happens when you decompose $u$ into eigenvectors of $A?$

Comment: I don't think there is an explicit form. the norm is between $\|A\|_1$ and $\sqrt{n}\|A\|_1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume this is over the reals.  You're looking for the norm of $A$ as a linear operator from $({\mathbb R}^p, \|\cdot\|_2)$  to $({\mathbb R}^p, \|\cdot\|_1)$.  By duality, that is the same as the norm of $A^T$ as a linear operator from $({\mathbb R}^p, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ to $({\mathbb R}^p, \|\cdot\|_2)$.  Now the set of extreme points of the unit ball of $({\mathbb R}^p, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is $\{-1,1\}^p$, i.e. the set of $2^p$ vectors with all entries $\pm 1$, so your answer is the maximum of $\|A^T v\|_2$ for $v \in \{-1,1\}^p$.

Comment: Just tested this with a quick script.  Duality is great!